# iOS selector not getting called for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I've got some fairly simple code, and am trying to figure out why the uibarbuttonitem isn't triggering the selector:

TableView's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // this line adds a button to top right
    let addNewChecklistItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add,
                                                    target: nil,
                                                    action: #selector(self.addNewChecklistItemToDataModel))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addNewChecklistItemButton
}
```

Method called:

```
@objc func addNewChecklistItemToDataModel() {
    print("adding new item...")

    <...>
}
```

The button is being added (was not visible before I put this code in) and when I press it the button click animates but my console doesn't show the printed text.

After reading [UIBarButtonItem selector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834375/uibarbuttonitem-selector-not-working), **I'm wondering if the fact that my `UITableViewController` is embedded in both a `UITabViewController` and `UINavigationViewController` is effecting the button's scope? If not, anyone see something I'm missing?**

Answer (score 2):

Target shouldn't be nil

```
 let addNewChecklistItemButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add,
                                                target: self,
                                                action: #selector(self.addNewChecklistItemToDataModel))
```